# SQL needed to get a subset of locations based on lat/long with a min/max distance constraint

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table with 500 location records that has a similar structure to:

```
id, name, lat, long
```

Lat & long are decimal (float) location values.

My need is to return a random 100 record set that are a minimum 200 meters and a maximum 500 meters away from each other. I'm familiar with using the great circle formula to get the distance between two points. However, I have no idea how to write a select statement to compare all locations against each other to ensure the distance requirements for the random 100 selected? Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated. My only tools are a MySQL database so the solution needs to be written in MySQL SQL. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what have you tried thus far?

I'm assuming the unit of measure for lat and long are Meters?

you're going to need to join the table to itself and compare lats and longs of 500 locations to all 500 other locations - this will return a full dataset of 250k records that will be slimmed down by the distance condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT p.latitude1 AS latitude1, p.longitude1 AS longitude1, p.latitude2 AS latitude2, p.longitude2 AS longitude2,
    (((ACOS(SIN((latitude2*PI()/180)) * SIN((latitude1*PI()/180))+COS((latitude2*PI()/180)) * COS((latitude1*PI()/180)) * COS(((longitude2- longitude1)* PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) AS distance
    FROM places p
    )
WHERE distance > 200 AND distance < 500
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: this is not a correct solution, since the table does have only latitude and longitude fields, not latitude1, latitude2 and longitude1, longitude2 fields. your goal was good, but is should be joined... ( WHERE places p1, p2) and (SELECT p1.latittude AS latitude1, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking at 500 metres then take some short cuts and pretend this is an xy space and use simple trigonometry. Can you even get away with a square instead of donut ?

You could use that as the first cut and then to proper maths on the remainder.

Your second cut will now be small enough. Assign a random no to each and take top X. Voila

**edit** For the first part, cheat and use Google maps. Find out what fraction of a degree equates to 500 metres at the equator. Use x +/- that value and the same for y. Quick and dirty first cut. **ok it won't work at the poles! **